# Writing to an absolute file path using Bonobo

Tags: python, etl, bonobo-etl

I'm using standard Bonobo writers for file output (CsvWriter etc).

If these are passed an absolute path ('/data/output.csv') they will assume it is relative and thus trigger 'resource not found' errors.

This is especially a problem when using Bonobo within a Docker container, as it's a common pattern to write to an absolute path which is a volume mount point.

What's the best way to get Bonobo to accept absolute paths?

Comment: I'm not sure the approach is sound here. What you probably want to do is fix your reliance on hard-coded absolute paths. I might consider refactoring such that you build your path's, for example, based on a root path specified in a config or environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `bonobo` defines a filesystem "service" called `fs` that points to your local directory. This service is the default filesystem used by all readers and writers provided in `bonobo` core.

I would avoid thinking of files locations as absolute, because it means that you make your software depend on a specific filesystem structure. Instead, think about "file containers" (which happens to be directories on your local filesystem, but that's an implementation detail), and think how files are organized within each "file container".

Bonobo uses [PyFilesystem2](https://www.pyfilesystem.org/) to abstract those containers. The goal is to not hardcode anything about the system, and instead allow easily to configure your data pipeline at runtime.

You can define more filesystem services to logically bind different paths to some business logic. In your case, let's say that `/data` is where "data" goes, you could define a filesystem service of your own that maps to this directory:

```
import bonobo

def get_services():
    return {
        'fs.data': bonobo.open_fs('/data'),
    }

def get_graph():
    return bonobo.Graph(
        bonobo.CsvReader('input.csv', fs='fs.data'),
        ... # etc
    )

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bonobo.run(get_graph(), services=get_services())
```

This will allow a nice separation of concerns, and will greatly enhance the portability of your transformation.

Of course, you could also override the default filesystem:

```
import bonobo

def get_services():
    return {
        'fs': bonobo.open_fs('/data'),
    }
```

And you can define more than one filesystem, someone may have:

```
import bonobo

def get_services():
    return {
        'fs.input': bonobo.open_fs('/input_data'),
        'fs.output': bonobo.open_fs('/output_data'),
    }
```

By having the service definitions separated from the actual graph implementation, you'll gain the ability to switch the filesystem depending on your surrounding env (dev laptop, production, compute cluster, ...). It allows for example to work with local files on the development boxes, and switch to AWS S3 storage on production.

What would be even better is to read the defaults from the environment.

To work correctly in a docker container, just define your "data" filesystem to point to "/data" (or to `os.environ.get('DATA_PATH', '/data')`, even better). Then open a local file from this abstracted filesystem.

Hope that helps!

P.S. The fact that if you provide an absolute path to a reader it joins it incorrectly ignoring the leading "/" is a bug, tracked as [#211](https://github.com/python-bonobo/bonobo/issues/211). The correct behavior would be to raise an exception, I think.